# ¿Me pueden explicar que hace el siguiente código?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, nodejs, sailsjs

Estoy tratando de cargar en una sección de una interfaz a otra usando **AngularJS (Angular 1)**, **nodejs** y **sails**. Ya existe algo que lo hace, pero aun no comprendo el funcionamiento, espero que me puedan ayudar este es el codigo del controlador.

#### Código del controlador

```
    $scope.menuSeleccionado = function (index) {

        console.log(index);

        menu = document.getElementsByClassName("usuarios");
        angular.element(menu).removeClass("active");
        inner = document.getElementsByClassName("content-inner-list");
        angular.element(inner).addClass("hide");
        actual = document.getElementById("usuarios" + index);
        angular.element(actual).addClass("active");
        actualInner = document.getElementById("contactEstado" + index);
        console.log("ActualInner="+actualInner);;
        angular.element(actualInner).removeClass("hide");

    };
```

#### codigo de la interfaz

```
        <ul class="list list-blue list-usuarios scroll">
<li>
    <div class="title-list shadow">
        <span class="cell-right"></span><span class="cell-left">Usuarios Activos <div class="n-user">({{usados}})</div></span>

    </div>

    <img ng-If="!cargaMenuUser" src="../images/loader.gif" class="load-user">


    <ul ng-If="cargaMenuUser" class="list content-inner-list">
        <li class="usuarios" ng-repeat="user in usuarios | filter:searchField" ng-If="user.status === 'true'" ng-click="menuSeleccionado($index)" id="usuarios{{$index}}">
            <a ng-href="#/usuarios/{{user.usuario}}"><span>{{user.usuario}}</span><span>{{user.tipo}}</span></a>    
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

PD. es un tipo dashboard donde selecciono un usuario del menú y me tiene que mostrar sus datos. Es un proyecto avanzado pero requiero implementar algo parecido en otra sección pero no entiendo que hace la `función(index)`.

Comment: Creo que el `$index` es como una especie de numeración que tiene cada usuario en la lista, es como si tuvieran 1, 2, 3, etc, eso creo.

Comment: si, lo puse por consola y son los indices de los usuarios pero en si toda la función no se que hace....

Comment: Lo que hace la funcion, es que toma los identificadores, y le asigna y remueve las clases, dependiendo de el index y todo lo demas, puedes verlo, puedes agregarle puntos de interrupcion.

Answer (score 0):

Muestra unas opciones del menú cuando le das *click* y oculta a todas las demás. Todo valiéndose de la concatenación de *usuario+index* que está como `id` de las opciones.

```
<li id="usuarios{{$index}}"></li>
```

Comment: Esto... menu = document.getElementsByClassName("usuarios"); obtiene esto <li class="usuarios" ng-repeat="user in usuarios | filter:searchField" ng-If="user.status === 'true'" ng-click="menuSeleccionado($index)" id="usuarios{{$index}}"> ??

Comment: Si @AlbertoRojas