# enviar datos entre componentes Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0

estoy utilizando routerLink para enviar un id de un componente con una lista de restaurantes a otro componente a través de la URL

`[routerLink]="['../restaurant-menu', restaurant.id]"`

en el otro componente lo utilizo de la siguiente forma

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.restaurantId = this.router.snapshot.params['id']
  getRestaurantMenu(this.restaurantId)
}

restaurantMenu: void[]

getRestaurantMenu(id): void {
this.RestaurantsService.getRestaurantMenu(id)
    .subscribe(
        restaurantMenu => this.restaurantMenu = restaurantMenu,
        err => {
            console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Todo funciona correctamente la primera vez que entro a un restaurante, y carga su menú, el problema es que cuando me devuelvo a la lista de restaurantes y entro a uno diferente se me carga el menú del primer restaurante al que entre, tengo que refrescar la pagina manualmente para que cargue el menú correcto.

No sé si sea que el id se actualiza luego de llamar la función de getRestaurantMenu() porque sin importar cuantas veces salga y entre a restaurantes distintos siempre sera el menú del primer restaurante al que entre el que se muestra además si hago esto:

```
<p> {{restaurantId}} </p>
```

El número de id que se muestra en pantalla es el correcto. he intentado distintas formas de pasar ese id pero el resultado es el mismo, ¿cuál podría ser el problema? gracias

Comment: soy nuevo en esto pero tendras que limpiar antes de llamar un nuevo fromulario de tu menú, es lo que entendi de acuerdo a algo que yo no sabia y lo pregunté... http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36046/me-pueden-explicar-que-hace-el-siguiente-c%C3%B3digo/36059#36059 pero yo ya lo tenia implementado sin saber que hacia, pero es igual un menú de usuarios.

Comment: Mira, échale un vistazo a [esto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37157838/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes), está en inglés

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Comment: Hola, disculpas por no comentar nada, tenia mucho tiempo sin entrar, pero ya el problema esta resuelto, en resumen, en el servicio que utilizaba tenia una función que al insertar el primer id dejaba de funcionar pues trataba de hacer un replace() de una parte de la url que ya no existía cuando enviaba un segundo id, lo solucione limpiando los datos antes de volver a hacer el replace(), gracias por la ayuda y disculpas de nuevo por la tardanza.

Answer (score 1):

Si no estoy equivocado, el problema lo tienes en la subscripción al servicio del router.

Antes de intentar explicarte la solución que yo veo, recomendarte que leas y busques información acerca de los 'Observables' y de la librería RxJs, puesto que el problema que planteas está relacionado con ello.

Supongo que lo que has llamado router será de tipo ActivatedRouter y que tendrás en el constructor del componente algo del estilo:

```
 constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,...){}
```

El servicio ActivatedRoute expone como 'Observable' los parametros de la URL actual. Puedes subscribirte a dicho servicio de dos maneras, directamente:

```
 //Cada valor emitido por el 'stream Observable' produce un nuevo valor  en la subscripción. 
 //Cada vez que el parametro 'id' cambien en la URL, se verá reflejado en la función subscribe:
 this.route.params.subscribe(...)
```

o bien a través del snapshot, (tu caso):

```
//Al subscribirte al snapshot, únicamente, el primer valor que le llegue despúes de subscribir, 
//será el único que será reflejado en la función subscribe. 
//Aunque el valor del parametro 'id' cambie a lo largo del tiempo, dichos cambios 
//no se verán reflejados.

this.route.snapshot.params.subscribe(...)
```

Éste es el motivo por el cuál, tu código no refleja los cambios del parametro 'id'.

Para solucionarlo:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.switchMap(params:Params => this.RestaurantsService.getRestaurantMenu(params['id']))
        .subscribe(
            restaurantMenu => this.restaurantMenu = restaurantMenu,
            error => console.log(error)
   )      
}
```

En caso de que necesites almacenar el 'id' del restaurante para otros menesteres, podrías hacerlo también:

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.route.params.subscribe(
      params:Params => {
         this.restaurantId = params['id'];
         this.RestaurantsService.getRestaurantMenu(this.restaurantId))
           .subscribe(
              restaurantMenu => this.restaurantMenu = restaurantMenu,
              error => console.log(error)
   )      
}
```

Comment: es una muy buena explicación y la implemente como dijiste, funciona pero sigo teniendo exactamente el mismo problema, lo solucione utilizando esta información https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9811#issuecomment-264874532  

me parece una solución un poco 'tramposa' pero funciona y es lo que usaré hasta encontrar algo mejor, gracias

Comment: Es extraño que no te funcione así... yo tengo un aplicación con un código igual al que te he puesto y funciona sin problema. ¿Has probado a abrir el depurador de chrome mientras navegas y ver si emite algún error?

Comment: si claro, siempre lo tengo abierto, el unico mensaje que muestra es este:   XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:5050/api/restaurants/1/menu".    el id 1 aparece en cualquier restaurante al que entre

Answer (score 1):

Creo que necesitas utilizar otro hook, como **OnChanges**, que se usa como `ngOnChanges()` en vez de `ngOnInit()`, ya que puede ser que estés cargando varios componentes en un sólo **module.ts** o **routing.ts**. Recuerda que al utilizar `ngOnInit()` se carga todo lo necesario **una sola vez** y no puedes cambiar ese componente, por lo que puede que se cargue al principio vacío y nunca espere recibir tu **restaurant.id**.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta resuelto.

En resumen, en el servicio que utilizaba tenia una función que al insertar el primer id dejaba de funcionar pues trataba de hacer un replace() de una parte de la url que ya no existía cuando enviaba un segundo id, lo solucione limpiando los datos antes de volver a hacer el replace().

Gracias por la ayuda y disculpas de nuevo por la tardanza.